# Defining $a^n b^{n^2}$ with one existential SO binary relation

Tags: reference-request, finite-model-theory

> Is it possible to define the language:

$$L = \{ a^n \; b^{n^2} \}$$

> using an existential second order sentence over strings (ordered structures with unary predicates $U_a(x), U_b(x)$) using only one binary relation?

The sentence should have this form: $\exists M ( \exists B_1,...,B_n ( \varphi ))$ where:

- $M$ is a binary relation
- $B_i$ are monadic
- $\varphi$ is first order with signature (available relations) $\sigma = \langle <, U_a, U_b \rangle$

If not, how to prove it? (or cite a textbook in which I can find similar exercises)

Answer (score 3):

First off, I assume you also want to have a binary relation on the domain, acting as a linear order: <. Furthermore, I assume you want to deal with existential second-order logic, which in general allows more than one existential quantifiert.

Then, you can employ Fagin's theorem: [wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagin%27s_theorem)
And what remains to show is that you can recognize the language $a^{n}b^{n^{2}}$ in polynomial time. Can you do that?

**Edit:**
Now, since it is clarified that you indeed want to just have an existential binary relation, consider the following:

- Büchi-Elgot-Trakthenbrot tells us that regular languages (which yours is not, but that needs a prove) are exactly those that can be described by MSO. The prove gives already big insights in how many different variables you need.
- Those languages definable in MSO are exactly those that are definable in existential MSO (see for this *Finite Model Theory* by Ebbinghaus and Flum, thm 6.2.3)
- Those languages definable in existential SO are those recognizable in NP, that's Fagin's theorem.

So you have that e-MSO matchs the regular languages. If you can prove that the different existential quantifiers in BET are necessary for recognizing a language and a binary relationvariable cannot encode the unaries, you are done.

A different approach (possibly more fruitful) is to argue the following way:
The constraint $a^2 = b$ is a meta constraint. You have to emulate this inside your language to get it in the object-world. Now im general SO over the empty signature is strong enough for such, but this is a different exercise. So you have to show two things:
Is your framework strong enough to emulate $x \mapsto x^2$ relative to the discrete order? Pay attention, Beth's Definability Theorem does fail in general in the finite, as does Craig's Interpolant Theorem (both for FO). This is also in above's book, 3.5.1. 
If you succeed in doing so, you still have to following problem: You need to get the "meta-size" of $U_a$ and $U_b$ into the object language. This is possible if you allow existential quantifiers of the form "exists exactly n many x:", which is possible in FO. However, you can only do this for a fixed number, additionally, you cannot get the "object-size" into the meta language. You could employ counting to test for sizes. In the MSO setting, they are of the form "$C_n(X)$ which is satisfied iff $ X mod n = 0$. These are not possible to emulate with just a binary relationvariable and FO. Can you show that even using those, you cannot get enough?

**Another edit**: Lets consider the solution with two binary relations, $R$ and $S$. I'll furthermore use $\bot$ as the smallest element of the order, $\top$ as the largest.

- $\forall x, y: (x,y) \in R \implies U_a(x) \wedge U_b(y)$
- $\forall x: ((x,\top) \in R \iff x = \bot) \wedge ((\bot,x) \in R \iff x = \top)$
- $\forall x: \exists y: (x,y) \in R$
- $\forall y: \exists! x: (x,y) \in R$
- $\forall x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2: x_1 < x_2 \wedge U_a(x_1) \wedge U_a(x_2) \wedge (x_1, y_1) \in R \wedge (x_2, y_2) \in R \implies y_2 < y_1$

Well, $R$ does split $U_b$ into $|U_a|$ many equivalence classes, each of which is not empty and the smaller the values in $U_a$, the large the corresponding values in the factorized $U_b$. A model of this sentence can look like this (numbers being the elements in $U_a$ and letters being the elements in $U_b$ factorized by the equivalence relation induced by $R$.

> w = 1-2-3-cc-bbbbbbb-a

What is left now is to make sure that the equivalence classes have the appropriate size. For this, note that we can indeed encode $x \mapsto x^2$ inside a binary relation (somewhat). See here that if $n = 1$, we have to append 1 element to the end and if $n = m + 1$, then for this one element more in $U_a$, we have to add as many elements to $U_b$ as we did for m, and two additional ones ($(n+1)^2 - n^2 - (n^2 - (n-1)^2) = 2$, aka when considering adding +1 repeatedly to $n$, one has to add 1, 3, 5, ... to $n^2$).

So, let's encode this behaviour with $S$:

- $\forall y_1, y_2: (y_1, y_2) \in S \implies U_b(y_1) \wedge U_b(y_2)$
- $\forall y: \neg (y, \top) \in S$ (probably redundant)
- $\forall y_1: (\exists y_2: (y_1, y_2) \in S) \implies (\exists! y_2: (y_1, y_2) \in S)$
- $\forall y_1: (\exists y_2: (y_2, y_1) \in S) \implies (\exists! y_2: (y_2, y_1) \in S)$
- $\forall y_1, y_2: (y_1, y_2) \in S \implies (\exists x_1, x_2: (x_1, y_1) \in R \wedge (x_2, y_2) \in R \wedge \neg \exists x_3: (x_1 < x_3 \wedge x_3 < x_2) \wedge x_1 < x_2)$
- $\forall y_1: (\exists x_1, x_2: x_1 < x_2 \wedge (x_1, y_1) \in R) \implies \exists y_2: (y_1, y_2) \in S$

This asserts that $S$ acts only on $U_b$, that if it is defined, it'll be uniquely defined (an injective partial function so to say, I'll use it from now on as a function), nothing is mapped to the largest element and whenever "$y_2 = S(y_1)$", than $y_2$ is in the equivalence class induced by the direct successor of the inducer of the equivalence class of $y_1$. Furthermore, $S$ is defined for each element that is not member of the "least" equivalence class.

With the help of this auxiliary function, we can control the size of the equivalence classes produced by $R$:

- $\forall x: \bot < x \wedge U_a(x) \implies (\exists x': x' < x \wedge (\neg \exists x'': x' < x'' \wedge x'' < x') \wedge (\forall y: (x', y) \in R \implies (x, S(y)) \in R \wedge \exists^2 z: U_b(z) \wedge (x, z) \in R \wedge \neg \exists q: S(q) = z \wedge \forall w: (x, w) \in R \implies (w = z \vee \exists y: (x', y) \in R \wedge w = S(y)))$

This formula expresses that for each element in $x \in U_a$, which is not the smallest one, there is a next smaller one $x'$. The elements which are paired with $x'$ in $R$ translated with $S$ are paired with $x$ in R, there are two additional elements which are not the image of any of those. Lastly, there are no elements paired with $x$) besides these two additionals and those that came from $x'$.

The following is now up to you:

1. Prove that all models of this sentence are words of the form $a^nb^{n^2}$
2. Prove that every word of the form $a^nb^{n^2}$ does satisfy this sentence
3. Show that you can indeed encode the two relations into one

Comment: Addendum: When you want to keep your restrictions (still assuming the ordering is intrinsic to the model), then you have to show/ disprove if you can encode the graph of $x \mapsto x^2$ into a relation without using numerals, addition and multiplication symbols. Furthermore, you have to use some sort of recognizing the number of $x \in U_a$. I'd start both proves with full SO and counting-SO resp. and work your way backwards until you (possibly) hit a problem.

Comment: Yes I assume a linear order (ordered structures) but I asked for ONLY ONE existential binary relation.

Comment: Then the comment stands. You need 2 things to show: Can you encode numerals, addition and multiplication/ quadratation into a single binary relation with the full help of FO? Hint: Whenever you can specify a 'new' relation in relationship to existing ones, you can omit this relation and have an equivalent formula. E.g. the successor relationship is easily defined on finite linear orders. Show or disprove this. For the second part, assume $(a,b) \in M \iff a*a=b$. Can you show that there is a finitely definable map, sending $U_a$ to a numeral and $U_b$ as well?

Comment: For the second part: The graph of the multiplication is recoverable from certain supersets of it. Can you show that you can(not) encode enough information in this superset to be helpful for the second task? As a starting point, show that counting MSO as a map is (not) sufficient (without the help of full second order). (cMSO contains formulae $π_n(X)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which are true iff |X| is a multiple of n.) If you find an argument that this is not sufficient to help, youre done

Comment: Thanks! Can you put your comments in the answer (which in the actual form it simply repeats what I asked and Fagin's theorem cannot be applied due to the restrictions). Furthermore, if the question is simply an exercise (I'm not an expert of FMT so I cannot judge its "hardness") can you point a reference to a textbook where I can find one or more FULL examples of how to face a similar exercise. If it is not an exercise, then can you explicitly say if the answer is Yes or No, and expand the sketch of the proof?

Comment: As an additional comment: Besides FMT, you might want to look into "Descriptive Complexity Theory"

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer! Just a direct question: can you tell me if the answer is *no* and if you have a complete proof in mind? (as I said I'm not an expert and the only way to formally tackle this problem that comes to my mind is to use Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games)

Comment: I've added the argument I'd follow with a critical parts missing. The proves left open should not require any knowledge of FMT altogether. You should be familiar with using induction, easy choice and some usual logic.

Comment: Thank you! But I think I found a shorter/easier solution (I posted it as a self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of struggling I found an easy answer by myself:

We can "define" a ternary relation:

$T(x,y,z) \equiv M(x,y) \land M(y,z) \land M(z,x)$

Then we can define $L$ in this way:

- $\exists M$ such that
- $\forall x,y \;.\; U_a(x) \land U_b(y) \to x < y$ ($a$s before $b$s)
- $\forall z \;.\; U_b(z) \to \exists x, y \;.\; U_a(x) \land U_a(y) \land T(x,y,z)$ (for all $b$s there is a pair of $a$s and ...)
- $\forall x, y, z_1, z_2 \;.\; U_a(x)\land U_a(y) \land U_b(z_1) \land U_b(z_2)  \;.\; T(x,y,z_1) \land T(x,y,z_2) \to z_1 = z_2$ (... there is a disticnt pair of $a$s associated with each $b$)
- $\forall x,y \;.\; U_a(x) \land (U_a(y) \to \exists z \;.\; U_b(z) \land T(x,y,z)$ (... and there is no "unmapped" $a$)

the number of distinct $a$s pairs is exactly $n^2$

Comment: Here is a counterexample to your 'solution': Take $U_a = \{ a, b \}, U_b = \{ 1 \}$ and $M$ the full relation (with or without $(1,1)$, that does not even matter). Also: you should really reformat your last axiom, what's standing there is unsensible.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. What do you mean with $U_a=\{a,b\}$? ($U_a$ should only contain positions). And with "full relation"? Btw I didn't wrote the obvious $\forall x U_a(x) \leftrightarrow \lnot U_b(x)$

Comment: "($U_a$ should only contain positions)" I guess you have a missunderstanding here. A word-model is a finite set equipped with a linear order and a partition into unary relations, one for each charakter. This gives a whole class of models for each word, all isomorphic. $U = \{a, b, 1\}$, ordered in the way I've written them and $U_a = \{ a, b \}$, $U_b = \{1 \}$ thus gives one of many isomorphic models for the word $\alpha \alpha \beta$.

Comment: Concerning the "full relation": For a set $U$, a full, binary relation $M$ is just $M = U^2 = \{ (a,b) \mid a \in U \wedge b \in U \}$.

Comment: What are $\alpha, \beta$ in $\alpha \alpha \beta$? Unless I'm missing something from FMT (I started  reading "Elements of Finite Model Theory" a few days ago) words should be from $\{ a, b\}^*$, the "universe" are the natural numbers  (with order relation)  and $U_a, U_b$ are unary relations (sets) on the elements of the universe i.e. numbers: so we can write $U_a(x)$ (or equivalently $x \in U_a$) where $x$ is a number (position); but I cannot understand the meaning of $a \in U_a$. Probably I still don't grasp the elementary topics of FMT.

Comment: I assumed you'd know what an isomorphism between $\sigma$ structures for a fixed signature $\sigma$ is. If you do not, you should start with a basic book like "Mathematical logic" by Ebbinghaus et.al. If you do, it's easy to see that my structure is the same as $U' = \{1, 2, 3 \}, U_a = \{1, 2 \}, U_b = \{3\}$ and $1 < 2 < 3$. Your confusion is, however, understandable, since I mixed my universe $U$ in sorts, which also appear as letters in the alphabet. So, the $a$ from $U_a$ and the $a \in U$ are two different ones. To get around that, I used the word $\alpha \alpha \beta$ instead of $aab$.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear! I'm thinking if adding $\forall x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,z_1,z_2 \;.\; T(x_1,y_1,z_1) \land T(x_2,y_2,z_2) \land (x_1 \neq x_2 \lor y_1 \neq y_2) \to z_1 \neq z_2$ can fix it.